# how to create vertx in scala

Tags: scala, vert.x

The build.sbt is as follows:

```
name := "ScalaVertxTest"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
libraryDependencies += "io.vertx" %% "vertx-lang-scala" % "3.6.3"
```

In Scala file, just trying to create vertx instance as follows:

```
package com.example
import io.vertx.scala.core._
object Main {
    def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello Vertx Scala")
    var vertx = Vertx.vertx()
```

}

sbt compile command generates following error message:

```
com/example/Main.scala:3:11: object vertx is not a member of package io
[error] import io.vertx.scala.core._
[error]           ^
[error] com/example/Main.scala:12:17: not found: value Vertx
[error]     var vertx = Vertx.vertx()
[error]                 ^
[error] two errors found
```

}

How to create Vertx instance in Scala?

Answer (score 0):

I was having problem building in Intellij IDE.

Compiled using sbt in console, program builds correctly.